# "Half-Blooded Prince" vs "Half-Blood Prince"

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

We all know there is the novel called **"Harry Potter And The Half-Blood Prince"**

**"half-blood"** is compound adjective modifying Prince.

But, what is difference when we use **"half-blooded Prince"** instead of **"half-blood Prince"**? Are they the same?

I hope to receive your advice. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do people actually use *half-blooded* as opposed to *half-blood*? It seems a few do. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half+blood%2C+half+blooded&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalf%20blood%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chalf%20blooded%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I would interpret a half-blooded prince as being someone who only has half the amount of blood in him that he ought to have, similar to how someone who is half-witted has only half the wits he should have. So very likely a half-blooded prince would be a dead prince.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you bleed a prince, but you stop half way, you would have a half-bled prince. But wouldn't that then also be a half-blooded one?

Comment: It seems to me it's always mixed-blood, but usually cold-blooded and often full-blooded. "A full-blooded Cherokee, he predicted to me the time and the place that the trouble would start." - Where Are You Tonight? (Journey Through Dark Heat), by Bob Dylan. "They'd turn a full-blooded city boy into a full-blooded city man." – From All The Nasties, by Elton John with lyrics by Bernie Taupin.

Comment: So I'd say the choice of "half-blood" (rather than "-blooded") was a literary choice between two grammatical possibilities. I'm not a Harry Potter fan, but in the movies (at least) they use "mud-blood" as a derogatory term. Maybe it just sounds a bit more pungent than mud- (or half-) "blooded."

Answer (score 2):

- "**Half-blood**" in this book's title is a [*noun adjunct*](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsANounAdjunct.htm),
  formed from the slang(?) term in the Harry Potter universe for a
  witch or wizard who has one non-magical parent. It is derived from
  the *noun* "half-blood."
- "**Half-Blooded**" is a [*participle adjective*](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/what-is-a-participial-adjective.html) (just like
  "cold-blooded"), and also derived from this in-universe slang, now in
  *verb* form. Being "half-blooded" means "being endowed with half-magical, half-muggle lineage".

Grammatically, both function as adjectives and convey the same meaning. In terms of nuance, the difference is more  subtle.

To my ear, "**The Half-Blood Prince**" sounds like a specific title or honorific given to a particular person, i.e. this prince's identity is *entirely defined by* his half-blood status, so "Half-Blood Prince" is a proper noun.

However, "**The Half-Blooded Prince**" seems more like "the prince who happens to be a half-blood," but that detail is of lesser importance and does not define him wholly.

One might call any prince who is a half-blood a "half-blooded prince," but there is only one Half-Blood Prince.